# A proper error-of-fit measure to evaluate log-linear model prediction?

Tags: error, metric

I want to evaluate predictions from a log-linear model. Because the response variable (`y`) varies over several orders of magnitude, standard measures like RMSE or MAE get easily skewed by some big values. What would be the good way to evaluate prediction?  RMSE or MAE of `ln y` can be a good measure?

Answer (score 1):

You can in principle use percentage errors, e.g., the Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE) or its weighted analogue ([wMAPE](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/5055557_Advantages_of_the_MADMean_Ratio_over_the_MAPE)), which will take the scale of your data into account. However, these error measure have issues; for instance, they will penalize over-forecasts more strongly than under-forecasts, so use with caution (see [here](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/224009542_Percentage_Errors_Can_Ruin_Your_Day_%28and_Rolling_the_Dice_Shows_How%29)).

RMSE/MAE on logged data could also be a possibility - it's hard to say without knowing your data.